# jQuery Animation Leaves Unnecessary Styles

Tags: jquery

When I run the following jQuery animation sequence:

```
$('#task').animate({ backgroundColor: fadeColor }, 50)
          .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000)
          .animate({ backgroundColor: originalBG }, 1000);
```

It leaves unneeded styles on my table row when complete (below)

```
<tr id="task29" onclick="TaskEdit('29');" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 1;">
```

These styles are messing with those defined in my CSS file (specifically some hover styles).  Does anyone have a recommendation on removing them.  I'm using jQuery 1.3.1.  I've tried adding a

```
.attr('style', '');
```

to the end of the chain, but that didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: more detail about how it's messing with your CSS styles, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want to do i think is more appropriate to use jquery UI and pulsate/highlight effect :)

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/addClass

Apparently the addClass method can take a duration.  Make classes for your animations and give this a try.  You should be able to removeClass if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Like Stuard said, using class seem a good idea.

But if you want to do what you said: (certainly a bad idea...)

```
$('#task').animate({ backgroundColor: fadeColor }, 50)
      .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000)
      .animate({ backgroundColor: originalBG }, 1000, function(){
         $(this).removeAttr('style');
      });
```